# How can I set up a macro to send a command in a discord channel at specified times?

Tags: autohotkey, discord

I'm trying to set it up so that I can activate a script on AutoHotKey that will use my discord app in the background and send a specified message every three hours. It would be best if the three hours were set on specified times, such as 12, 3, 6, 9, 12, etc.

I'm mostly having a hard time understanding the send command, but I'm sure I need information on how to get it to use the discord api properly as well, so the more you give me the better. I was going to do this using the chrome web browser and opening a tab with the discord website on there so it didn't interfere with anything I'm doing, but I figure now that doing it through the application will be the best way.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
Send, #
Send, c
Send, h
Send, Enter
```

All I got when trying this code is the windows ding sound. I have not learned enough of this stuff yet, so again, the more direction I can get here the better.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading through the "Getting started" section of the help documentation to get a solid understanding of the basics.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm

Looking at what you have so far, it's important to understand what you're sending. Each of these, `!^+#`, act as one-time modifier keys `alt`, `ctrl`, `shift`, and `windows-key`. If you want to send these as actual characters, you need to enclose these in braces - like this, `Send , {#}`. The same goes for the enter-key; without the braces, it will just send the letters E, n, t, e, and r. Additionally, you can combine all of your sends into one - like so, `Send , {#}ch{enter}`.

As for setting it to run on every third hour, you can accomplish this with `SetTimer`. I would recommend checking it out in the [help documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) for usage and examples. If you want it to run once every three hours, that is simple enough; if you want it to run on hours divisible by three, then you'll have to also have it check the time. Here is an example that checks every hour if the hours of the current time are divisible by three.

```
f1::
GoSub, l_Timer
SetTimer , l_Timer , 3600000 ; 60min/hour x 60sec/min x 1000ms/sec
Return

l_Timer:
If ( Mod( SubStr( A_Now , 9 , 2 ) , 3 ) = 0 )
MsgBox , The current hour is divisible by 3.
Return
```

Note that on the first run, the timer must run out before activating the sub-routine. You can make it run immediately first by adding a `GoSub , [label]` line as I did.